# Blocked from using pip3

Tags: ubuntu, python3, pip

Default python is 2.7; default python3 is 3.6, which is the version I use; Ubuntu version 18.04.
I'm trying to get newly downloaded python libraries to be installed in a python 3 library.

```
charles@BW2:~$ pip3 --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
  from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name 'main'
```

What to do?

Comment: Instead of "$ pip..." do "$ python3 -m pip..."?? Also check whether your current dir has a file called "main.py"

Comment: "$ python3 -m pip --version" yields the pip in the python 2.7 library. Using pip3 instead yields a "No module named pip3" error. There is no main.py in /usr/bin/.

Comment: And if you just start python3 at shell what version is shown?

Comment: did you actually install `python3-pip`? (if there's no module named pip)

Comment: Version shown using python3 as the command is 3.6.7. pip3 was installed in /usr/bin/ on Apr 3 2019.

Comment: Ok then I'm out of ideas... Other than (apt) remove and reinstall python3 and python3-pip 

Comment: Evidently this is a Debian/ubuntu [bug](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5447) Which links to https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 which has suggrstions

Comment: Thank you, this has pointed me to the correct explanation of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
python3 -m pip ARG [ARG [...]]
```

or

```
/path/to/python3 -m pip ARG [ARG [...]]
```

The latter is the typical way to invoke a module such as pip from a specific interpreter. The former will only work if `python3` is on your PATH and is a valid interpreter.

Comment: @cbro630, Unfortunately due to limitations I cannot yet comment on the question itself, but have you considered (1) installing a second, newer Python interpreter and (2) creating a virtual environment for installing libraries? Although these do not address your original issue, they may provide a suitable workaround.